# Twitter feeds are not loaded in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, twitter

I am using below code to load twitter feeds, Everything is working fine in chrome/Firefox but don't know why it is not working in IE8.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/ESPNcricinfo/cricketers-on-twitter" data-widget-id="286832583709442048" height="290" data-theme="light"  data-tweet-limit = 2 data-link-color="#0084B4">Tweets from @ESPNcricinfo/cricket-tweeters</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script> 
<br/>
http://jsfiddle.net/qfm3C/54/embedded/result/
```

Comment: Well, it was IE8...if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter updated the widgets.js script two days ago and have removed IE8 support. I can't find an official announcement but have just encountered the same issue. The script now relies on functions that are only available from IE9 onwards (e.g. Function.bind, Object.create, Array.forEach, Element.addEventListener) and checks for their existence and the browser user agent before continuing.

Comment: Ohhhh ! ..Thats why twitter official site widget is not appearing in IE8 also. e.g. https://blog.twitter.com/search/node/ie8

Comment: Here is twitter announcement link  https://twittercommunity.com/t/update-on-twitter-for-websites-ie7-and-ie8-browser-support/28234